# При попытке логина в виртуальную машину на Ubuntu Server 22.04 (напрямую и через ssh) возвращает обратно к вводу логина

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, авторизация

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла проблема с входом в виртуальную машину на Ubuntu Server.
Не пускает ни под одним логином (вернее пускает, но сразу выкидывает обратно).

пробовал подключиться по ssh, но после подключения сразу выкидывает:

```
C:\Users\User>ssh root@192.168.0.104
root@192.168.0.104`s password:

Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-169-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue 09 Jan 2024 01:55:26 PM MSK

  System load:                      0.19
  Usage of /:                       36.7% of 108.87GB
  Memory usage:                     10%
  Swap usage:                       0%
  Processes:                        316
  Users logged in:                  0
  IPv4 address for br-1d435b4c76c1: 172.20.0.1
  IPv4 address for br-7224601463ca: 172.18.0.1
  IPv4 address for docker0:         172.17.0.1
  IPv4 address for eth0:            192.168.0.104

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

13 updates can be applied immediately.
11 of these updates are standard security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

9 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm

New release '22.04.3 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Tue Jan  9 13:55:12 2024
Connection to 192.168.0.104 closed.
```

При этом развёрнутый в виртуалке Portainer работает, и доступ к веб интерфейсу есть

ftp на виртуалке не поднят, а sftp выдает следующее:

```
Статус: Соединяюсь с 192.168.0.104...
Ответ:  fzSftp started, protocol_version=11
Команда:    open "root@192.168.0.104" 22
Статус: Using username "root". 
Команда:    Pass: ********
Статус: Connected to 192.168.0.104
Ошибка: Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP on server: could not connect
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
```

в гугле решения не нашел, по тому обращаюсь к знатокам Stack**Overflow**

---

UPD:

Всё таки попал в рута из рекавери, вот такие строки нашел в `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Jan  9 16:33:11 portainer login[3165]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=root
Jan  9 16:33:14 portainer login[3165]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'root', Authentication failure
Jan  9 16:33:16 portainer login[3165]: pam_unix(login:auth): check pass; user unknown
```

---

UPD:

Проблема в `LinuxPAM`, как фиксить не понимаю. Смотрел пару гайдов по настройке `PAM` и ничего не понял

вот некоторые конфиги (из тех которые видел в гайдах):
`/etc/pam.d/sudo`
[image: 1]

`/etc/pam.d/sshd`
[image: 2]

[image: 2.1]

`/etc/pam.d/common-password`
[image: 3]

---

UPD:

При более детальном рассмотрении логов нашел вот такую ошибку:

```
pam unable to dlopen pam_limits.so#015 cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

ошибка в модуле pam_limits, а точнее в его отсутствии.

переустановка всех модулей или создание символической ссылки `/lib/security/pam_limits.so` на `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_limits.so` не помогла

Comment: Нельзя подключаться root по ssh, по умолчанию запрещено, нужно обычным пользователем.

Comment: доступ к ssh с root разрешен.
раньше доступ в виртуальную машину был, но после очередной перезагрузки не пускает **ни под одним логином**

Comment: вот например другой логин [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Va4u7eAW)

Comment: да и если доступ по ssh для root был бы закрыт, было бы сообщение `Permission denied` после ввода пароля, а меня вполне себе логинит, но потом сразу выкидывает

Comment: А что на сервере происходит можешь посмотреть `journalctl -u ssh -n15`

Comment: а как выполнить команду, если залогиниться никак нельзя? я просто пробовал по типу `ssh root@192.168.0.104 'journalctl -u ssh -n15'`, но вывода команды нет, и мгновенно отключает

Comment: да и дело даже не в ssh
меня и напрямую не пускает

Comment: вот как выглядит попытка входа в виртуалку напрямую [YouTube](https://youtu.be/0lBoDvP_sSY)

Comment: Без доступа к серверу ничего сделать нельзя, нужно как-то логиниться, заходить в  однопользовательском режиме, может оказаться что быстрее переустановить.

Comment: перекатывать не вариант, по тому сюда и написал, может кто знает лазейку

Comment: только что нашел вариант с попыткой упасть в рекавери и оттуда попробовать

Comment: Успешно! я залогинился в рекавери моде

Comment: в общем, на сколько я понял, проблема в `Linux PAM`

как её фиксить я не знаю. смотрел гайд по настройке `pam` но ничего не понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходим в **recovery** через **grub**, логинимся под рутом

Выполняем команду
`nano /etc/pam.d/*`

Так у нас по очереди откроются все конфиги `pam`

Если видим строку с `pam_limits.so`, комментируем её (добавляем в начале **#**) и сохраняем (**f2** затем **y** затем **enter**)

если строки нет, просто жмем **ctrl+x** для перехода к следующему файлу

Я знаю что это не лучшее решение, и оно создаёт уязвимость в системе авторизации, но в моём случае это решение подходит (ssh доступ есть только из локалки)

Ребутимся, и готово, нас успешно логинит